# How can I pass "this" into setTimeout callback?

Tags: javascript

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/M2W6Z/)

**code:**

```
<button onclick="this.disabled=true; setTimeout(function(){this.disabled=false;},500);">click</button>
```

`this` seems to refer to the window rather than the button. How can I pass the button object in so that I can re-enable it?

I'm aware of workarounds... I could give the button an ID and then grab it again, but I'm interested to know if I can somehow pass `this` in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is a defined by how a function is called.

```
foo.someFunc(); /* this is foo */
foo.bar.someFunc(); /* this is bar */
window.someFunc(); /* this is window */
someFunc(); /* this is window because window is the default */
setTimeout(foo.bar.someFunc, 500); /* this is window because you've passed a function and disassociated it from foo.bar */
```

If you want to pass it around between functions, you have to copy it to a different variable.

```
<button onclick="this.disabled=true; var that = this; setTimeout(function(){that.disabled=false;},500);">click</button>
```

Comment: Of course... solution is always so obvious. I've done this before too and then I forgot >.<

Comment: Was getting confused because I thought it was a closure and the variables would carry over inside, but `this` is an exception.

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly set the context of a function by binding it.

```
<button onclick="
  this.disabled=true;
  setTimeout(
    function(){this.disabled=false}.bind(this),
    500)">click</button>
```

Comment: Didn't know about this either. I guess this is similar to `.call` but for delegates. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice that the disabling works, just the enabling doesn't. This is because `this` isn't a local variable; it takes on its proper meaning when the event handler fires: no longer bound to the button.

[Try](http://jsfiddle.net/33Gpz/) this:

```
<button onclick="var self=this; self.disabled=true; setTimeout(function(){self.disabled=false;},500);">click</button>
```

BTW, try to avoid writing code inline like this. [Write proper handlers](http://jsfiddle.net/knwXd/) for great victory:

```
// HTML:

<button id="myBtn">click</button>

// JS:

window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener("click", function() {
      var self = this;
      self.disabled = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
          self.disabled = false;
      }, 500);
   }, false);
}
```

More verbose, yes, but ultimately far more maintainable.

jQuery makes it [even easier](http://jsfiddle.net/HSWhB/):

```
$(function() {
    $('#myBtn').click(function() {
      var self = this;
      self.disabled = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
          self.disabled = false;
      }, 500);
   });
});
```

Comment: Haha...thanks, but I'm almost offended (I didn't need that much explanation). But I guess I was asking a pretty basic question, so OK. I prefer separating the JS too, but I'm working on a legacy system and this is the way everything's already done (inline).

Comment: @Mark: Well you did not declare that, so I had to assume that you did not know. Don't be offended: advice is what we do here on SO.